# Render an element based on condition in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I render an element based on a condition in **React Native**?

This is how I tried:

```
render() {  
  return (
      <Text>amount is: {this.state.amount}</Text> // it correctly prints amount value
      </Button>
         {this.state.amount} >= 85 ? <button>FIRST</button> :   <button>SECOND</button>
      <Text>some text</Text>
  );
}
```

But this error message appears:

```
Expected a component class, got [object Object]
```

Comment: That error is probably because you are writing `<button>` instead of `<Button>`.
Component classnames are generally capitalised. Or *should* be capitalised, rather.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misplaced your `}`:

```
render() {  
  return (
      <Text>amount is: {this.state.amount}</Text>
      {this.state.amount >= 85 ? <button>FIRST</button> : <button>SECOND</button>}
      <Text>some text</Text>
  );
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error message. I've updated my question code, I have several elements inside the return. Maybe (even if I don't think ) that creates the error.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that you have to wrap everything inside a view.

```
render() {  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>amount is: {this.state.amount}</Text>
         {this.state.amount >= 85 ? 
           <button>FIRST</button> : <button>SECOND</button> 
         }
      <Text>some text</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```